# Expose JAXB-annotated objects through org.w3c.dom API

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I have some domain objects that are annotated using JAXB annotations. This can be used to serialise the object tree to an XML document.

Now, I would like to expose the same backing object tree through the standard `org.w3c.dom` API to leverage higher-level, DOM-based APIs. The difference is that I don't want to serialise the object tree because:

- I'd like to write back to the same tree through the DOM API
- When manipulating only parts of the tree, a full serialisation is not needed

Is there any library that implements the above? Or is this already possible through standard JAXB API?

Note: I know there is [`Marshaller.getNode(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#getNode%28java.lang.Object%29), but seems not to be implemented in the JDK's reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The `Marshaller.getNode(Object)` method is optional in the JAXB (JSR-222) specification.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#getNode%28java.lang.Object%29

I have targetted the following enhancement request against the next version of EclipseLink to have this behaviour added to MOXy:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/332762

---

You may be interested in `javax.xml.bind.Binder`.  It allows you to maintain an object graph and a DOM tree, if you make changes to one then you can apply them to the other.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html

Here is a link to an example of how this works:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feature request to MOXy! `Binder` seems to be able to do what I was looking for, more or less. I'll accept if it does, indeed.

Comment: I've now had some time to look into this. This does something similar to what I'm looking for. `Binder` allows for explicitly synchronising DOM and Object trees. I'm actually looking for a DOM tree wrapping the Object tree in a way that methods, such as `Node.appendChild()` will directly modify the underlying Objects